# AngularJS : Is it possible to compile a ng-repeat comment after it has been manually transcluded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/zYd13f4EelPcQqJrguVh?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module("inputGroupApp", []);

app.controller('numbersController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.data = {}
  $scope.data.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
}]);


app.directive('labelGroup', ['$compile', '$timeout', function($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
      'template'   : '<div class="label-group">' +
                     '<label class="label-group-label"></label>' +
                     '<div class="label-group-content"></div>' +
                     '</div>',
      'restrict'   : 'E',
      'transclude' : true,
      'replace'    : true,
      'link'       : function(scope, elem, attr, nullController, transclude) {

        var labelElem = elem.find('.label-group-label');
        var contentElem = elem.find('.label-group-content');

        transclude(scope, function(clone) {
          var tLabel = null;
          var tContent = null;

          angular.forEach(clone, function(node) {
            var $node = angular.element(node);

            // these nodes have been emptied by gutting their contents
            // is it a memory problem that the nodes themselves aren't destroyed?

            if ($node.is('label-group-label')) {
              tLabel = $node.contents(); 
              labelElem.append(tLabel);
            } else if ($node.is('label-group-content')) {
              tContent = $node.contents();
              contentElem.append(tContent);
            }
          });

          // why doesn't this work? i've tried compiling elem with no success either
          $compile(contentElem)(scope);

          console.log('contentElem ', contentElem);
          console.log('elem ', elem);
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

I'm trying to write a markup abstraction directive to wrap a label and corresponding content using custom elements that are discarded when their contents are placed where they should be in the new template. The content part of the label group could have directives within it, and they need to compile successfully.

The only part that I can't seem to get working is to have the transcluded dom elements that have not yet rendered (in this case, ng-repeat) actually compile. I'm successfully copying over the ng-repeat comments, but when I try to run use $compile to have the ng-repeat compile nothing happens. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

I'm starting to think that I may be approaching this problem incorrectly.

Comment: I think the elements still need to be appended to the DOM, since you're not returning a `$compile` function. Try `$node.append( $compile(contentElem)(scope) )`

Comment: The $node references are there to help iterate through the transcluded clone, since I need to pick out specific nodes and extract their contents. I'm taking the $node of interest to me, and then appending it directly into the elem reference where it belongs (labelElem or contentElem). When the template is replaced, the elem manipulations that take place in the transclude function via the .append() method are actually in the dom. In this case, I can actually see the ng-repeat directive comment in the dom, and can verify that the $scope properties it is iterating over exist, but it wont compile.

Comment: Hmm take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25489916/angularjs-ng-repeat-not-working-in-compilehtmlscope

Comment: Thanks, that question is the same issue. I was able to solve the issue I was having and posted an answer below. Thanks for your help, Ben!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was attempting to modify the transcluded clone's dom structure before running compile, specifically removing the nested ng-repeat comments from their parent wrapper. Since angular maintains scope references via parent elements, this was effectively causing the ng-repeat to behave as expected since it had no scope data to repeat over (so it just remained as a comment).

The solution that I came up with was to run the compile steps within the transclude function, and then modify the dom by appending the nodes outside of the transclude function.

Here's the updated code that appends the transcluded elements outside the transclude function and after they are compiled.

http://plnkr.co/edit/E3Ha0xS6NUFIefohKve9?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module("inputGroupApp", []);

app.controller('numbersController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.data = {}
  $scope.data.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
}]);


app.directive('labelGroup', ['$compile', '$timeout', function($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
      'template'   : '<div class="label-group">' +
                     '<label class="label-group-label"></label>' +
                     '<div class="label-group-content"></div>' +
                     '</div>',
      'restrict'   : 'E',
      'transclude' : true,
      'replace'    : true,
      'link'       : function(scope, elem, attr, nullController, transclude) {

        var labelElem = elem.find('.label-group-label');
        var contentElem = elem.find('.label-group-content');

        var tLabel = null;
        var tContent = null;

        transclude(scope, function(clone) {


          angular.forEach(clone, function(node) {
            var $node = angular.element(node);

            // these nodes have been emptied by gutting their contents
            // is it a memory problem that the nodes themselves aren't destroyed?

            if ($node.is('label-group-label')) {
              tLabel = $node.contents(); 
            } else if ($node.is('label-group-content')) {
              tContent = $node.contents();
            }
          });

          $compile(contentElem)(scope);
          $compile(labelElem)(scope);

        });

      contentElem.append(tContent);
      labelElem.append(tLabel);
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: I thought that post would help. Could you post your revised code?